# How can I slice a string with Meteor's helpers while pulling it from a collection?

Tags: javascript, meteor, slice

I am trying to display the first 150 characters of each blog post as they are iterated through in a loop. The posts are being displayed on an archive page, like so:

```
<ul>
  {{#each listPosts}}
    <li>
      <h4>{{postDate}}</h4>
      <a href="/blog/{{_id}}"><h1>{{postTitle}}</h1></a>
      {{#markdown}}{{postBody}}{{/markdown}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Like this, the postBody is returned in full, but I thought I could slice the remainder of the string after 150 characters and display a shortened version of the text.

```
Template.Blog.helpers({
  "listPosts": function() {
    return Posts.find()
  },
  "synopsis": function() {
    var string = postBody.slice(0, 150);
    return string
  }
});
```

My thought was to replace `{{postBody}}` with `{{synopsis}}` and render a shortened version of the text, but "synopsis" doesn't seem to have access to the collection as `listPosts` is worked through.

How can I gain access to the value of postBody, slice the string, and inject the new value as each list item is being iterated through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have access to the appropriate data context. So, if `listPosts` objects have the `postBody` attribute, you can access `postBody` via `this.postBody`:

```
Template.Blog.helpers({
  "listPosts": function() {
    return Posts.find();
  },
  "synopsis": function() {
    var string = this.postBody.slice(0, 150);
    return string;
  }
});
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was missing. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Please note that missing semicolons may cause undesired operation of your Meteor application, due to the minifying process on deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just displaying the data you could create a handlebars helper:

```
Template.Blog.helpers({
  "listPosts": function() {
    return Posts.find();
  },
  "first150": function(postBody) {
    return postBody.slice(0, 150);
  }
});
```

And in your template

```
<ul>
  {{#each listPosts}}
    <li>
      <h4>{{postDate}}</h4>
      <a href="/blog/{{_id}}"><h1>{{postTitle}}</h1></a>
      {{#markdown}}{{first150 postBody}}{{/markdown}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```